# Mathematic sequence further elements

Tags: f#, functional-programming, sequence

Let's say I have following equation [image: ai]. My goal is to create sequence which returns next elements of this. Here's my solution and it works:

```
let rec factorial(n:float) =
    match n with
    |0.0 -> 1.0
    |n -> n * factorial(n-1.0)

let seq1 = Seq.initInfinite( fun i -> factorial(float(i)) / sqrt(float(i)+1.0) ))
```

Now, analogically, I would like to create sequence which return elements according to equation:
[image: e do x]

I've got some code, but it's wrong so how to make it work?

```
let seq2(x:float) = Seq.initInfinite(fun a -> let i = float(a)                                      
                                              (1.0/factorial(0.0)) + System.Math.Pow(x,i)/factorial(i) )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you skip the (1.0/factorial(0.0)) part of the equation (or maybe I misunderstood the question).

edit: i.e

```
let seq2(x:float) = 
  Seq.initInfinite(fun a -> 
    let i = float(a) in 
      System.Math.Pow(x,i)/factorial(i))
```

edit: to truncate a seq you can use 'take' and to sum you can use 'sum'. As in

```
let seq2sum nbelems = 
    seq2 >> Seq.take nbelems >> Seq.sum
```

then you get `seq2sum 12 3.0` equal to approx 20 :-)

Comment: Lol, I didn't check that `(x^0) / 0! = 1 / 0!` earlier. It works now.

Comment: By the way, how to get sum of `x` elements of sequence?

Answer (score 3):

The great thing about functional languages is that you can have your solution be as close an expression of the original definition as possible.

You can avoid explicit type declarations for most functions:

```
let rec factorial = function
| 0 -> 1
| n -> n * (factorial (n-1))


let e x n = 
    seq { 0 .. n } 
    |> Seq.map(fun i -> x ** (float i) / float (factorial i))
    |> Seq.sum
```

In the infinite series, you will have to take the first n entries before you sum, as an infinite series will never finish evaluating:

```
let e' x n = 
    Seq.initInfinite(fun i -> x ** (float i) / float (factorial i))
    |> Seq.take n
    |> Seq.sum

e 1.0 10 //2.718281801
e' 1.0 10 //2.718281801
```